# "undefined as outuput in the channel chat

Tags: javascript, discord.js

im currently trying to start with the discord.js.
i made my first bot and im trying to do some basic things.
Somehow i get a undefined in my channel chat after the automatic reply.
Would be nice if someone could figure out why this happens.

```
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) 
{
    if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
        var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
        var cmd = args[0];

        args = args.splice(1);
        switch(cmd) {
            // !ping
            case 'ping':
                bot.sendMessage
                ({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'pong'
                });
                break;
            case 'hello':
            if (channelID == 632276762436567060)
            {   
                bot.sendMessage
                ({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Check private message'+
                    bot.sendMessage
                    ({
                      to: userID,
                      message: 'hello'  
                    })   
                })
            };
                break;
            default:
                bot.sendMessage
                ({
                    to: channelID,
                    message: 'Unknown Command'
                });         


         }
```

MeToday at 8:05 PM
!hello
BOTToday at 8:05 PM
Check private messageundefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `bot.sendMessage` to add the results to the message of a different `sendMessage` call. It's including "undefined" in the message because that's the return value for that inner call to `bot.sendMessage`.

Instead, you should move the `to: userID` `sendMessage` out of the other one.

Change this part:

```
bot.sendMessage
({
    to: channelID,
    message: 'Check private message'+
    bot.sendMessage
    ({
      to: userID,
      message: 'hello'  
    })   
})
```

To this:

```
bot.sendMessage
({
    to: channelID,
    message: 'Check private message' 
});

bot.sendMessage
({
    to: userID,
    message: 'hello'  
});
```

Comment: Please also note that `sendMessage` is deprecated, use the `send` method instead!

Comment: @Caltrop I've never used discord.js - is that just as easy as changing `sendMessage` to `send` and keeping the object argument the same?

Comment: @TheDexter Glad I could help, and please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left  so visitors on the search page will know this question has been solved, and it gives me some reputation points as well 8)

Comment: @Ruzihm unfortunately not. `send` is a Method in GuildMember, TextChannel, User and some other Objects. The way it works is by doing `channel.send("Some string here", {/*MessageOptions here*/})`

Further reading: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageOptions
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel